# Sort date/time objects (latest first)

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to order date objects by date/time (latest first) using code below. The ordering is not correct. I think the `compareTo` method needs to be implemented differently to achieve the required sorting ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class DateSorter {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        List<DateObject> list = new ArrayList<DateObject>();

        DateObject d1 = new DateObject("2012-12-05" , "11:21:19");
        list.add(d1);

        d1 = new DateObject("2012-12-05" , "11:20:19");
        list.add(d1);

        d1 = new DateObject("2012-12-05" , "11:20:19");
        list.add(d1);

        d1 = new DateObject("2012-12-04" , "10:20:19");
        list.add(d1);

        d1 = new DateObject("2010-12-07" , "13:20:19");
        list.add(d1);

        d1 = new DateObject("2012-12-05" , "11:20:19");
        list.add(d1);

        Collections.sort(list);

        for(DateObject d : list){
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }

}

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateObject implements Comparable<Object> {

    private String date;
    private String time;

    public DateObject(String date, String time) {
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {

        DateFormat formatter;
        Date date1 = null;
        Date date2 = null;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
            date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException npe){
            System.out.println("Exception thrown "+npe.getMessage()+" date1 is "+date1+" date2 is "+date2);
        }

         return date1.compareTo(date2);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){       
        return this.date+" "+this.time;
    }

}
```

This is the output displayed :

```
2012-12-05 11:21:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-04 10:20:19
2010-12-07 13:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
```

This output should be :

```
2010-12-07 13:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-05 11:21:19
2012-12-04 10:20:19
```

Update : when I modify the compareTo method to :

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {


    DateFormat formatter;
    Date date1 = null;
    Date date2 = null;  
    DateObject other = (DateObject) o;

    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
        date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(other.date + " " + other.time);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException npe){
        System.out.println("Exception thrown "+npe.getMessage()+" date1 is "+date1+" date2 is "+date2);
    }

     return date1.compareTo(date2);

}
```

The output is  :

```
2010-12-07 13:20:19
2012-12-04 10:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-05 11:21:19
```

Which is still incorrect as 2012-12-05 should appear before 2012-12-04

Comment: Did you try debugging? Put a breakpoint in `compareTo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are parsing the same date twice:

```
date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
```

should probably be:

```
date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
DateObject other = (DateObject) o;
date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(other.date + " " + other.time);
```

and you should probably test that o is a DateObject and not null before trying to cast it and use it.

**EDIT**

Just tried your updated code using `return date2.compareTo(date1);` and I get:

```
2012-12-05 11:21:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-05 11:20:19
2012-12-04 10:20:19
2010-12-07 13:20:19
```

which is in descending order (note that the last date is in 2010).

Comment: @user470184 You need to invert your comparison for descending order: `return date2.compareTo(date1);` - See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the date to itself, not the object passed in

```
 date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
 date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
```

Where's `o` used ?

What does `DateObject` give you, btw ? It looks like a `Date` object. Note that `java.util.Date` holds date *and* time info, confusingly. If you use a standard date object then you don't have to write a comparator. Better still, you could investigate [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which has a better, more intuitive and thread-safe API.

Comment: The DateObject in this case is a stripped version of a larger object which contains date/time fields

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is :

```
 date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
```

should be

```
 date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(((DateObject)o).date + " " + ((DateObject)o).time);
```

and you can also do this to get rid of the cast :

```
public class DateObject implements Comparable<DateObject> {
...
public int compareTo(DateObject o) {
    date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(o.date + " " + (o.time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
DateObject other = (DateObject) o;

date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(this.date + " " + this.time);
date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(other.date + " " + other.time);

date2.compareTo(date1);
```

Notice the last line. You say you want the latest to be the first. In this case you should compare date2 to date1 not vice versa, because date1.compareTo(date2) will sort in the ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

DateObject should implement Comparable. In your compareTo method, date2 needs to be derived from the object passed into the method.